# Angular momentum of rolling body about a moving point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

[image]

**I have searched on google,youtube everywhere about by topic but there no relevant content.

I need a help in finding angular momentum about point C as shown in diagram.Body is performing pure rolling motion.

Please also provide proof for angular momentum abot moving point.

I know that angular momentum about a point is translational motion of centre of mass about that point + rotation motion of body about COM

I am confused because of C is moving point.
**

Comment: Yes I agree that this is homework type question but i didn't find any information regarding this topic from my available source, so please explain this concept.